# how to create hexadecimal identity auto increment column sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Can anyone tell me how to create an identity column with auto increment storing hexadecimal values in sql server 2008 r2?
(I am looking for this function to use as OrderID and PaymentID in my small time shopping cart)

Comment: Just create it as int and cast it to `binary(4)` to see it in hex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL doesn't have native hex data type. You can save it as varbinary, but still it would need conversion.

```
    SELECT CONVERT( VARBINARY(8), 100)
    --> 0x00000064
```

I would say that you use new computed column where you put these hex values, and let identity column remain int.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NEWSEQUENTIALID() but not a sequential but unique

```
col uniqueidentifier default NEWSEQUENTIALID()
```